# Showing that the solutions of the differential equation $u''' - 3u'' + 4u = 0$ form a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

My textbook has the following problem:

> Show that the solutions of the differential equation $u''' - 3u'' + 4u = 0$ form a vector space. Find a basis of it.

This is a third-order linear homogeneous ODE.

I found the solution to be

$$u(x) = C_1 e^{2x} + C_2 xe^{2x} + C_3 e^{-x}$$

Assuming this solution does form a vector space, a basis would be

$$\{ e^{2x}, xe^{2x}, e^{-x} \}$$

But I'm unsure of how to show that this solution forms a vector space? I know the requirements of a vector space, and I understand how to conventionally show that a set of elements is a vector space, but I'm unsure of how to show this for a solution of a differential equation.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please explain how this is done and demonstrate it. I'm not looking for a demonstration of all of the conditions, just the main two (closure under addition and scalar multiplication).

Comment: If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions, then you need to show $y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ is also a solution. So take three derivatives of $y$ and plug them into the DE.  If you get $0$, it's a solution.

Comment: You need not have solved the equation to demonstrate that the solutions form a vector space.

Comment: @ThePointer: See  https://www.stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%201/Exercise%2010/StraussPDEch1s1p10.pdf or problem number 4 on page 2: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~blumstei/MathDocs/Homework/M545PDEs/HW1.pdf

Comment: @B.Goddard This doesn't make sense, since the solution is a function; it's not clear why you're suggesting that we need to take three derivatives for this.

Comment: @Moo Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: Because to show that it's in the space of solutions, you have to show it is a solution.  So you have to plug the function into the DE, which means you need to write down the derivatives.

Comment: @B.Goddard See https://www.stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%201/Exercise%2010/StraussPDEch1s1p10.pdf No need to take 3 derivatives of $y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$.

Comment: I see them taking derivatives.  How many times in that solution do you see $u'''$?

Comment: @B.Goddard yes, but I thought you said to take three derivatives of $y = c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2$?

Comment: One way or the other, you have to take those derivatives.  Either all at once, as I suggested, or $y=cy_1$ and $y=y_1+y_2$ separately.  Then you plug them in the DE and show that you have formed new solutions.  THEN you can conclude your closure properties.